# External SMTP (gmail) configured on phabricator not working

Tags: gmail, phpmailer, phabricator

I have configured Gmail as an External SMTP with phabricator instance. It was working fine and suddenly stopped working. PHPMailer configuration is as follows;

[image: phabricato PHPMailer configuration]

The outbound mails are being queued and not delivered. Also tried with 'tls' protocol.

***21713 Queued for Delivery T1204: task name***

While tracing the message, the following error message is shown

```
   ##trace log##
PROPERTIES
ID: 21713
Status: queued
Related PHID: PHID-TASK-j7wyjg5iwadfyezpul7a
Message: ***SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.***
    PARAMETERS
    subject: T1204: task name
    from: PHID-USER-5qhdvvho4nt5oallclmk
    subject-prefix: [Task]
    vary-subject-prefix: [Commented On]
    thread-id: maniphest-task-PHID-TASK-j7wyjg5iwadfyezpul7a
    is-first-message: 
    exclude: []
    mailtags: ["maniphest-comment"]
    is-bulk: 1
    to: ["PHID-USER-5qhdvvho4nt5oallclmk"]
    reply-to: T1204+10+3233c43281706b19@phabricator.mydomain.com

    HEADERS
    Thread-Topic: T1204: task name
    X-Herald-Rules: none
    X-Phabricator-To: <PHID-USER-5qhdvvho4nt5oallclmk>
    X-Phabricator-Cc: <PHID-USER-5qhdvvho4nt5oallclmk>
    #
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Synchro. I tried with 'tls' as well and its not working.

Comment: "Queued but not delivered" doesn't make much sense - you're sending via SMTP, so either it sends or it doesn't - there is no queueing in PHPMailer. You need more info from the rejection to be able to diagnose this.

Answer (score 1):

For SMTP authentication, are you using a gmail address or are you using a @mydomain.com address?

From what I understand, when you authenticate with the Gmail SMTP servers you need to use a valid Gmail address.  You can set the From address to something different within PHPMailer, but you won't be able to authenticate with that address (unless your mydomain.com is going through Google Apps).

Also, to clarify the SMTP servers for Gmail use Port 465 with SSL OR Port 587 with TLS.

Alternatively, I think the queuing is being done by Phabricator, not by PHPMailer.  Take a look at your queued tasks -- there may be some huge job that is going and holding everything else up.

See this:  [secure.phabricator.com/T5512/](https://secure.phabricator.com/T5512)

Comment: Thanks Mooseknuckles. Its phabricator issue and not PHPMailer!!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell because this is not the running code and this config is not complete, but ssl on port 587 definitely won't work. For gmail it should be tls on 587. For stock PHPMailer, you need to set both `SMTPAuth` and `SMTPSecure` properties to have it do both encryption and authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. I have tried with the protocol 'tls' as well